# What does $\pi(x)$ usually mean in importance sampling?

Tags: sampling

I'm learning about particle filters, and most expositions start with importance sampling, so now I'm learning about importance sampling. I'm not sure if I'm correctly interpreting a paragraph in this article:

Arulampalam, Maskell, Gordon, and Clapp (2002), "A Tutorial on Particle Filters for Online Nonlinear/Non-Gaussian Bayesian Tracking" ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.1144&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), page 178, left column, near the middle:

> We therefore have a discrete weighted approximation to the true posterior, $p(\mathbf x_{0:k}|\mathbf z_{1:k})$. The weights are chosen using the principle of *importance sampling* [3], [12]. This principle relies on the following. Suppose $p(x)\propto\pi(x)$ is a probability density from which it is difficult to draw samples but for which $\pi(x)$ can be evaluated [as well as $p(x)$ up to proportionality]. In addition, let $x^i\sim q(x),i=1,\ldots,N_s$ be samples that are easily generated from a proposal $q(\cdot)$ called an *importance density*. Then, a weighted approximation to the density $p(\cdot)$ is given by
>   $$p(x)\approx\sum_{i=1}^{N_s}w^i\delta(x-x^i)$$
>   where
>   $$w^i\propto\frac{\pi(x^i)}{q(x^i)}$$
>   is the normalized weight of the $i$th particle.

I take this to mean the following:

- $p(x)$ is a probability density, meaning $\int p=1$, which we want to approximate. Unfortunately, it happens to be difficult to sample from $p(x)$. Additionally, it is hard to evaluate $p(x)$ for a given $x$.
- $\pi(x)$ is a density which is proportional to $p(x)$, meaning there is some constant $M>0$ such that $\pi(x)=Mp(x)$ for all $x$. We don't call $\pi(x)$ a "probability" density because $M=\int \pi$ is not necessarily equal to $1$, and in fact computing $M$ may be difficult. But it so happens that computing $\pi(x)$ for a given $x$ is easier than computing $p(x)$. Still, it's difficult to sample from $\pi(x)$, which would be the same as sampling from $p(x)$.
- $q(x)$ is some other density, which must be nonzero wherever $\pi(x)$ is nonzero, but otherwise doesn't need to resemble $\pi(x)$ too closely. The density $q(x)$ is not necessarily a probability density, so $\int q$ is not necessarily $1$ (?), although it doesn't seem to matter for what follows. It must be easy to sample from $q(x)$, *and* it must be easy to evaluate $q(x)$ for a given $x$.

I'm still hung up on the "as well as" language in square brackets in the source. It may just a wording issue, but I don't know what they're trying to convey there, and I hope I'm not missing something. The other problem is that one of their references is Doucet, Godsill, and Andrieu (2000), "On sequential Monte Carlo sampling methods for Bayesian filtering" ([PDF](ftp://ftp.idsa.prd.fr/local/aspi/legland/ref/doucet00b.pdf)), which uses the letter $\pi$ to represent the importance function instead, and which doesn't introduce any auxiliary density proportional to the target distribution $p$.

1. Am I right so far?
2. Is there some subtle reason why these two articles use $\pi$ to represent different things? Or is it just an unlucky coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point in importance sampling is that you transform a desired expectation multiplying by one.

Suppose that you have a random variable $X$ with density $f$. The [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) tells you that for some function $g$, the expectation of $g(X)$ is
$$
  \mathrm{E}[g(X)] = \int g(t)\,f(t)\,dt \,  .
$$
Now, suppose that you have another probability density $h>0$ which is easy to sample from. Multiplying by one, we have
$$
  \mathrm{E}[g(X)] = \int g(t)\,\frac{f(t)}{h(t)}\,h(t)\,dt = \mathrm{E}\!\!\left[g(Y)\frac{f(Y)}{h(Y)}\right] \, ,
$$
in which $Y$ has density $h$. The strong law of large numbers tells us that if $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ is an IID sample from $h$, then
$$
  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N g(Y_i)\frac{f(Y_i)}{h(Y_i)} \longrightarrow \mathrm{E}\!\!\left[g(Y)\frac{f(Y)}{h(Y)}\right]
$$
with probability one, when $N\to\infty$.

You can interpret the sum above as the integral $\int g\,d\xi$, in which $\xi$ is a discrete measure that puts mass $f(Y_i)/(N\,h(Y_i))$ on each $Y_i$. Physicists like to talk about the "density" of $\xi$ using Dirac deltas. That's what your book does.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and it's quite simple! So it seems like I'm not missing anything from the quoted description...?

Comment: Looks good, Chris. Also, do some simple simulations to see it working. For example, find the mean of a Gamma rv sampling from a standard lognormal rv. It takes only a bunch of lines of R code.

Comment: Okay, good idea!